# Posting child objects to a database with php

Tags: php

I am trying to post child objects to a database with php and can't figure this out, any help is appreciated.  The top clientId to invAmount posts fine, but the invoiceDetails child objects is where I am getting confused, I tried a while loop but no luck, I am a ui guy not php so I'm out of ideas.

The post:

```
{
"clientId": "5",
"invNumber": "2",
"invProject": "Test Project",
"invDescription": "Test",
"invDate": "09/20/2013",
"invAmount": "5000",
"invoiceDetails": [
    {
        "invRowDescription": "Description 1",
        "invRowHours": "50",
        "invRowRate": "50",
        "invRowTotal": 2500
    },
    {
        "invRowDescription": "Description 2",
        "invRowHours": "50",
        "invRowRate": "50",
        "invRowTotal": 2500
    }
]
}
```

The php controller

```
<?php
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);


// Independent configuration
require 'medoo.php';
$database = new medoo(array( 
 // required 
  'database_type' => 'mysql', 
 'database_name' => 'dbname', 
 'server' => 'server', 
 'username' => 'user', 
 'password' => 'pw' 

));

$database->insert("invoiceSummary", array(
     "clientId" => $_POST['clientId'],
     "number" => $_POST['invNumber'],
    "project" => $_POST['invProject'],
    "description" => $_POST['invDescription'],
     "date" => $_POST['invDate'],
     "amount" => $_POST['invAmount']
));

while($rowInv = mysqli_fetch_array($_POST['invoiceDetails'])) {
    $database->insert("invoiceDetails", array(
       "clientId" => $_POST['clientId'],
"number" => $_POST['invNumber'],
    "description" => $_POST['invRowDescription'],
    "hours" => $_POST['invRowHours'],
    "rate" => $_POST['invRowRate'],
    "total" => $_POST['invRowTotal'],
));
}

   echo json_encode('success');
   ?>
```

Comment: `while($rowInv = mysqli_fetch_array($_POST['invoiceDetails'])) {` should be `foreach($_POST['invoiceDetails'] as $details){` (and use `$details` instead of `$_POST` in that loop. I'd avoid abusing the `$_POST` superglobal though.

Comment: yeah, it's a little weird, I have a workaround in there because I am using backbone.js on the ui